# Multiple nested multi-index selection, filtering and computation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index df that stores all my stocks execution orders.

I need to compute the counts of each existing open orders and working orders of each type of combination type, ie strategy type.

there could be multiple rows of a specific combination type. this helps with automation follow up activities such as amend stoploss, close all, execution, and etc.

i have problem selecting the specific data and tabulating the counts, cause there are many variations and layers so i want to use a more pythonic df / multiindex friendly way to process it to prevent overheads.
from the left to right, the row indexers are sequential.

ie there will a set of orders in AAA, BUY, 0, 0, 0, oo, 0, 0
and also in AAA, BUY, 1, 1, 0, oo, 0, 0
for example.
so i want to count the total counts of each type of combination.

the more important combination are in the first 6 indexers.
ie asset direction acc_no str_no type_asset o_type

i know i can use loop to find all combination one by one and add up the counts, but worried of overheads and time performance.

i tried this:
but this gives me the error
but assume this even works, this only checks 1 row and 1 combination

```
orders_df.index.values[0][0:5].isin([("AAA", "BUY", 0, 0, 0)]).any()

 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

tried this

```
orders_df.index.isin([("AAA", "BUY", 0, 0, 0)]).any()

 ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.
```

this:

```
orders_df.index.values.isin([("AAA", "BUY", 0, 0, 0)]).any()

 ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.
```

i think i may have to use iterrows(), lambda or comprehension but im new to python and not strong in this...

would truly greatly appreciate if someone can provide me with ideas on how to filter/scan and search for all existing combinations and their counts or perhaps len.

Thank you!

the df looks like this. there are more columns for follow up processing and computation but i cannot squeeze in all. i have no problems with columns but facing issues on the rows indexers.

```
                                                                                         size    level
asset direction acc_no stratg type_asset o_type seq sub_type  ref           Id     code               
AAA   BUY       0      0      0          oo     0   0         sdw           jag    qwe    5.0  12937.0
                              1          oo     0   1         fdc           dfr    qwe    0.5  12937.3
                                                1   2         fdc           gb     qwe    0.5  12938.6
                       1      0          oo     0   0         fgf           gd     qwe    5.0  12937.8
                              1          oo     0   1         sse           sfg    qwe    0.5  12937.8
                                                1   2         dcv           rsf    qwe    0.5  12937.8
                       3      0          oo     0   0         asd           adgs   qwe    5.0  12934.1
                              1          oo     0   1         qwe           sdfsr  qwe    0.5  12934.6
                                                1   2         ikj           agsrgs qwe    0.5  12934.0
                       5      0          oo     0   0         bfg           dfd    qwe    5.0  12934.1
                                                              dfg           asfg   qwe    5.0  12932.0
                                                              fdf           asfdgs qwe    5.0  12933.6
                                                              hdt           afsd   qwe    5.0  12928.2
                              1          oo     0   1         dse           sdfsf  qwe    0.5  12931.7
                                                              fbg           afdsf  qwe    0.5  12927.7
                                                              fdd           qrd    qwe    0.5  12933.5
                                                              hnb           dfas   qwe    0.5  12934.8
                                                1   2         dfg           asfaf  qwe    0.5  12927.1
                                                                            sdf    qwe    0.5  12935.0
                                                              ews           dfsd   qwe    0.5  12931.5
                                                              fgd           fjfgh  qwe    0.5  12934.0
```

Comment: I think query should be used here, check second answer.

Comment: ok i will look into query, haven't look at it yet but yes it may helps. cause i was wondering if there is a way to scan all the rows on df and compute each combination counts without looping too many times